# Displaying a density plot from a bootstrap

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I have the following data frame:

`z<-data.frame(A=c(40, 41, 42, 45, 46, 47, 48, 46, 45, 38, 41, 42, 46, 39, 45, 47, 48, 50, 39, 41),  B=c('California', 'Arizona', 'Texas','Arizona', 'Arizona', 'Texas', 'California', 'California', 'Texas', 'California', 'Arizona', 'Texas', 'Texas', 'California', 'Texas', 'Arizona', 'California', 'California', 'Arizona', 'Arizona'))`

I'm relatively new to bootstrapping so would like to figure out how to do the following from 'scratch' (I'm aware there are packages in R which make the following task rather trivial).

I'd like to:

1. Obtain the sampling distribution of the mean numbers of hours worked by state.
2. Display a density plot for each state on the same plot

Comment: Bootstrapping has nothing to do with Bootstrap 4. Remove that tag.

Answer (score 2):

I am also new to bootstrapping. Please see if the following work flow makes sense.

First, sample the row with replacement for 1000 times and combine all resamples to one data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(5528)

z_re <- map_dfr(1:1000, function(i){
  z2 <- z %>%
    group_by(B) %>%
    sample_frac(size = 1, replace = TRUE) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(Time = i)
  return(z2)
})
```

Second, calculate the average by `B` and time of resample.

```
z_re2 <- z_re %>%
  group_by(B, Time) %>%
  summarise(Average = mean(A)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Finally, plot the data.

```
ggplot(z_re2, aes(x = Average, fill = B, color = B)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure if you need to bootstrap while considering the stratification (which is the group as used in the answer by @www).

Below is an implementation that just sample the rows of the data.frame with replacement, without considering the groups:

```
# function to calculate mean of A wrt B
mean_func = function(df)tapply(df$A,df$B,mean)

# replicate runs the function each time with a sampled data.frame
boot_res = t(replicate(1000,mean_func(z[sample(nrow(z),replace=TRUE),])))
> head(boot_res)
      Arizona California    Texas
[1,] 42.25000   43.66667 43.80000
[2,] 44.00000   45.25000 46.40000
[3,] 42.66667   41.88889 44.80000
[4,] 42.87500   47.33333 44.33333
[5,] 41.66667   45.16667 43.12500
[6,] 42.20000   42.09091 44.00000
```

In the matrix above you have a distribution for each group. To plot it, one can use base R:

```
COLS = c("#f08a5d","#b83b5e","#6a2c70")
names(COLS) = colnames(boot_res)
LIMS = round(range(boot_res))

plot(NULL,xlim=LIMS,ylim=c(0,0.8),xlab="Mean",ylab="Density")
for(i in names(COLS)){
lines(density(boot_res[,i]),col=COLS[i])
}
legend("topleft",fill=COLS,names(COLS))
```

[image]